# Hadoop mapred: attach sources howto

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

**I use:**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro-mapred</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
        <classifier>hadoop2</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

**Question:** How to attach sources to that classes?

Answer (score 2):

you can add another dependency, with the `sources` classifer

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro-mapred</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <classifier>sources</classifier>
</dependency>
```

See [the repo](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.avro|avro-mapred|1.7.7|bundle). You can also get the javadoc.